please help, im updating magento 2.3.5-p3 to 2.4.3 but im stuck in errors and erros here is one
[root@33 public_html]# composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]? y
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typoin the package name.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Potential causes:

A typo in the package name
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.
[root@33 public_html]#
here is my composer.json
{
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
"type": "project",
"license": [
"OSL-3.0",
"AFL-3.0"
],
"config": {
"preferred-install": "dist",
"sort-packages": true,
"allow-plugins": {
"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
"laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
"magento/magento-composer-installer": true
}
},

"require": {
    "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
    "ext-bcmath": "*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-hash": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-soap": "*",
    "ext-xsl": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "lib-libxml": "*",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "~1.4.1",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.11.0",
    "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.11.1",
    "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "~1.4.0",
    "composer/composer": "^1.9 || ^2.0",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.11.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.3",
    "laminas/laminas-captcha": "^2.10",
    "laminas/laminas-code": "^3.5.1",
    "laminas/laminas-crypt": "^3.4.0",
    "laminas/laminas-db": "^2.12.0",
    "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "laminas/laminas-di": "^3.2.0",
    "laminas/laminas-escaper": "2.7.0",
    "laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.0.0",
    "laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.13.0",
    "laminas/laminas-filter": "^2.11",
    "laminas/laminas-http": "^2.6.0",
    "laminas/laminas-i18n": "^2.7.3",
    "laminas/laminas-json": "^3.2.0",
    "laminas/laminas-mail": "^2.9.0",
    "laminas/laminas-mime": "^2.8.0",
    "laminas/laminas-modulemanager": "^2.7",
    "laminas/laminas-mvc": "^3.2.0",
    "laminas/laminas-server": "^2.6.1",
    "laminas/laminas-servicemanager": "^3.6.0",
    "laminas/laminas-session": "^2.10",
    "laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.9.0",
    "laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.2.1",
    "laminas/laminas-text": "^2.6.0",
    "laminas/laminas-uri": "^2.5.1",
    "laminas/laminas-validator": "^2.6.0",
    "laminas/laminas-view": "~2.12.0",
    "league/flysystem": "^2.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^2.0",
    "magento/composer": "1.6.0",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
    "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.2",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.6",
    "pelago/emogrifier": "^5.0.0",
    "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "~2.10.0",
    "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "1.0.8",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
    "ramsey/uuid": "~4.1.0",
    "symfony/console": "~4.4.0",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~4.4.0",
    "symfony/process": "~4.4.0",
    "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.4.0",
    "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
    "web-token/jwt-framework": "^v2.2.7",
    "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
    "wikimedia/less.php": "^3.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
    "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-pcntl": "Need for run processes in parallel mode"
},
"replace": {
    "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
    "magento/module-admin-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-admin-notification": "*",
    "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-amqp": "*",
    "magento/module-amqp-store": "*",
    "magento/module-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-asynchronous-operations": "*",
    "magento/module-authorization": "*",
    "magento/module-advanced-search": "*",
    "magento/module-backend": "*",
    "magento/module-backup": "*",
    "magento/module-bundle": "*",
    "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "*",
    "magento/module-captcha": "*",
    "magento/module-cardinal-commerce": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-customer-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-search": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-widget": "*",
    "magento/module-checkout": "*",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "*",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-cms": "*",
    "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "*",
    "magento/module-compare-list-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-config": "*",
    "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-configurable-product": "*",
    "magento/module-configurable-product-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-contact": "*",
    "magento/module-cookie": "*",
    "magento/module-cron": "*",
    "magento/module-currency-symbol": "*",
    "magento/module-customer": "*",
    "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-customer-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-customer-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-deploy": "*",
    "magento/module-developer": "*",
    "magento/module-dhl": "*",
    "magento/module-directory": "*",
    "magento/module-directory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-downloadable": "*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-eav": "*",
    "magento/module-elasticsearch": "*",
    "magento/module-elasticsearch-6": "*",
    "magento/module-elasticsearch-7": "*",
    "magento/module-email": "*",
    "magento/module-encryption-key": "*",
    "magento/module-fedex": "*",
    "magento/module-gift-message": "*",
    "magento/module-gift-message-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
    "magento/module-google-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-google-optimizer": "*",
    "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-cms-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product": "*",
    "magento/module-grouped-catalog-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-instant-purchase": "*",
    "magento/module-integration": "*",
    "magento/module-layered-navigation": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-api": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-assistance": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-frontend-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-log": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-quote": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-page-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-login-as-customer-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-cms": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-ui-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-integration": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-synchronization": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-media-content-synchronization-cms": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-metadata": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-metadata": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-metadata-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-cms-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-integration": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-renditions": "*",
    "magento/module-media-gallery-renditions-api": "*",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "*",
    "magento/module-message-queue": "*",
    "magento/module-msrp": "*",
    "magento/module-msrp-configurable-product": "*",
    "magento/module-msrp-grouped-product": "*",
    "magento/module-multishipping": "*",
    "magento/module-mysql-mq": "*",
    "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "*",
    "magento/module-newsletter": "*",
    "magento/module-newsletter-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-offline-payments": "*",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-page-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-payment": "*",
    "magento/module-paypal": "*",
    "magento/module-paypal-captcha": "*",
    "magento/module-paypal-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-persistent": "*",
    "magento/module-product-alert": "*",
    "magento/module-product-video": "*",
    "magento/module-quote": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-bundle-options": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-configurable-options": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-downloadable-links": "*",
    "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-related-product-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-release-notification": "*",
    "magento/module-reports": "*",
    "magento/module-require-js": "*",
    "magento/module-review": "*",
    "magento/module-review-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-robots": "*",
    "magento/module-rss": "*",
    "magento/module-rule": "*",
    "magento/module-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-rule": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-sequence": "*",
    "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
    "magento/module-search": "*",
    "magento/module-security": "*",
    "magento/module-send-friend": "*",
    "magento/module-send-friend-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-sitemap": "*",
    "magento/module-store": "*",
    "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-swagger": "*",
    "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
    "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
    "magento/module-swatches": "*",
    "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "*",
    "magento/module-tax": "*",
    "magento/module-tax-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-theme": "*",
    "magento/module-theme-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-translation": "*",
    "magento/module-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-ups": "*",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite": "*",
    "magento/module-user": "*",
    "magento/module-usps": "*",
    "magento/module-variable": "*",
    "magento/module-vault": "*",
    "magento/module-vault-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-version": "*",
    "magento/module-webapi": "*",
    "magento/module-webapi-async": "*",
    "magento/module-webapi-security": "*",
    "magento/module-weee": "*",
    "magento/module-widget": "*",
    "magento/module-wishlist": "*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",
    "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "*",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "*",
    "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "*",
    "magento/language-de_de": "*",
    "magento/language-en_us": "*",
    "magento/language-es_es": "*",
    "magento/language-fr_fr": "*",
    "magento/language-nl_nl": "*",
    "magento/language-pt_br": "*",
    "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "*",
    "magento/framework": "*",
    "magento/framework-amqp": "*",
    "magento/framework-bulk": "*",
    "magento/framework-message-queue": "*",
    "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
    "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
    "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
    "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
    "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7",
    "magento/module-csp": "*",
    "magento/module-aws-s3": "*",
    "magento/module-remote-storage": "*",
    "magento/module-jwt-framework-adapter": "*"
},
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "component_paths": {
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "components/jquery": [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
        ],
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
        "components/jqueryui": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
        ],
        "twbs/bootstrap": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
        ],
        "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce_4"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
        "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/"
    }
},
"prefer-stable": true

}


how to i change ea-php73 to ea-php74?
this is the issue because the one with php74 is working fine. please help. thanks.

I finally got it install it and it works but no products shows on website, I'm trying to install Elasticsearch but it impossible to make it works here is what i have tried.
sudo service elasticsearch start
Starting elasticsearch (via systemctl):  Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 [FAILED]
[root@33 ~]# Aug 08 19:56:17 server host systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:106)
Aug 08 19:56:17 serverhost number systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:88)
Aug 08 19:56:17 serverhost number systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.close(Node.java:989)
Aug 08 19:56:17 serverhost number systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:106)
Aug 08 19:56:17 myhostserver number systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:64)
Aug 08 19:56:17 my host server number systemd-entrypoint[11655]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$4.run(Bootstrap.java:192)
Aug 08 19:56:17 my host server number systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 08 19:56:17 my host server number systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Aug 08 19:56:17 my host serv number systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Aug 08 19:56:17 MY HOST SERVER NUMBER systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.


Try using the  --force-root-updates switch with composer require however, your replace section seems to be removing 99% of Magento - which is nice.

i had tried everything but i had found the issie, the issue was the php on cpanel even if you change it to php74 still doenst change, you have to go and change it manually and after it works.

Seems like your Magento is downloaded from github and your Magento is setup under app/code folder not in vendor folder, so if you want to upgrade using composer then magento must be installed in vendor via composer,
otherwise magento upgrade should not be there via composer.
Thank You!

i finally got it install it and it works but no products shows on website, im trying to install elasticsearch but it imposible to make it works here is what i have tried.

Take a backup your existing composer.json and then please try with given below composer.json.
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.3",
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.4.*",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}

Run this command.
composer update


i did that, now is asking me for elasticsearch, Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

This error indicates that Elasticsearch is not enabled on your server.
Since Magento 2.4.3, Elasticsearch is mandatory to run in the background.

Set up a local xampp server:

1.Download Elasticsearch version 7.17.0 (https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-7-17-0)
2. Follow this guide to set up Elasticsearch on your localhost XAMPP server. (https://mage2db.com/how-to-install-elasticsearch-in-xampp/)

On Ubuntu server:
Follow this tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-22-04


I am a server administrator and Certified Magento Developer from the looks of the error can you please try typing the command
sudo service elasticsearch start

and after that
systemctl status elasticsearch.service

Can you give me an screenshot of an output from the last command?
